# How exactly does event.preventDefault() affect the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, preventdefault

Based on someone's advice I added this line `$('body').on('touchstart', function(event){ event.preventDefault() })` in my mobile webapp to disable the native app bouncing in iOS. It works great for disabling the bounce but gives me some weird behavior elsewhere in DOM.

Click events that don't work, etc. I was hoping to get a better understanding of what this does and how to work around it's effects elsewhere in the DOM.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have these two lines:

```
  $('body').on('touchstart', function(e){ e.preventDefault() };
  $('#home').on('click', function(){ alert('home') };
```

If I comment out the `preventDefault` line then the `#home` line works. If I leave it in the #home line doesn't respond. `#home` is just a div nested in the `body`.

Any idea what could be causing this behavior? It's part of a bigger codebase so it;s hard to give you all the details but I don't even know where to start.

Thanks Again!

Comment: This is not native JavaScript, it's the [jQuery preventDefault method](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Actually, it is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault

Comment: @Niko: It's not a native method when called on the jQuery object: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L666

Comment: @Niko jQuery is cross browser it decided what native code to call based on what's available. In case Firefox is used you are correct but in case other browser is used, you are wrong.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`e.preventDefault()` tells the browser that if there is a default behavior for this event on this object, then skip that default behavior.

So, for example, if you had a submit button that the default behavior was to submit a form and you had a click handler on that button that did a `preventDefault()`, then the browser would not submit the form when the button was clicked.  A classic use of this might be when the form doesn't validate so you show the user an error message and don't want the form to be submitted to the server.

Or another example.  If you set up a click handler for a link and you call `e.preventDefault()` in that click handler, then the browser will not process the click on the link and will not follow the href in the link.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer jfriend00, can you look at my edit and see if you have any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning, that for example the 'click'-event bubbles, so when 'touchstart' is triggered somewhere else it may be canceled by the OP's code. And it's also interesting, that touchstart on iOS ist triggered for (nearly - I'm not sure right know) all touch events like moving the page around, zoom etc.

Comment: @insertusernamehere I posted some more info if you have any ideas. It's part of a larger codebase but I don't know where to start looking. Thanks.