# What does event.preventDefault() do exactly inside a submit button function?

Tags: javascript, events, submit, dom-events

Learning [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and I know this question isn't part of it but I've always wondered what the preventDefault part does:

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

When I opened the example in a page and removed the preventDefault, the page just doesn't refresh when I hit submit. So does that mean the default behavior of a submit button on click is to make a send the form data somewhere and then redirect the current page to somewhere else? By having preventDefault, this prevents it from happening? Is this event a Dom event?

Comment: Possible cublicate :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921210/how-exactly-does-event-preventdefault-affect-the-dom

Answer (score 10):

`event.preventDefault()` basically prevents event to fire. In the case of `submit` event. `event.preventDefault()` will prevent your form to submit.

We normally prevent `submit` behaviour to check some validation before submitting the form or we need to change values of our input fields or we want to submit using `ajax` calls. For this purpose, we prevent form to be submitted by using:

```
event.preventDefault();
// Here comes our custom logic
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921210/how-exactly-does-event-preventdefault-affect-the-dom) is a good read for your question. Hope this helps :)