# How does event.preventDefault work on event handlers that cannot be stopped?

Tags: javascript, web

I'm trying to understand how event objects work in the context of the .preventDefault() method. Now I now for example, if I use event.preventDefault on the on submit event handler, it'll stop me from firing the submit event. So I tried to use onclick event handler on the submit button with the event.preventDefault(), it also didn't allow me to submit the form. Technically speaking it's not possible to not allow the user to click a button. So I want to make sure and know what exactly the event.preventDefault does exactly in relation to event handlers. The code for reference is below. This also bring me to the question, what is the natural behavior of buttons declared in the form but are not defined with type submit?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prevent default example</title>
    <style>
      div {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div>
        <label for="fname">First name: </label>
        <input id="fname" type="text">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="lname">Last name: </label>
        <input id="lname" type="text">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="submit" type="submit">
      </div>
    </form>
    <p></p>
    <script>
      var form = document.querySelector('form');
      var fname = document.getElementById('fname');
      var lname = document.getElementById('lname');
      var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
      var para = document.querySelector('p');
      form.onclick = function(e) {
        if(fname.value === '' || lname.value === '') {
          e.preventDefault();
          para.textContent = 'You need to fill in both names!'
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How exactly does event.preventDefault() affect the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921210/how-exactly-does-event-preventdefault-affect-the-dom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event.preventDefault function prevents the browser from executing the native behavior.

In the case of the submit button, it will not submit the data to the server and reload the page in the process, it will leave the data processing up to you.

So if you want to submit your form data with AJAX for instance, you can define in what way you handle the data.

Comment: what about buttons declared in the form but are not defined with type submit? Is there natural behavior 'submit'?

Comment: If a submit button is defined inside the form, then it will always attempt to submit the data in the form to the server. If no path is defined, then it will submit it to the page itself. If you simply define a button inside the form, then it will not do anything. As a button does not have any native behavior in that context.

Comment: Also, for a submit button that I use an event handler of onclick, will the event itself be submitting or clicking? This is where I'm really confused..

Comment: If the user clicks the button, then the event onclick event will fire. If the user uses presses submit in the form without actually clicking the button, it will not fire the onclick event.

Comment: thanks makes sense, so the event object in this case will be clicking.

Comment: Yep. Please don't forget to accept my answer. And if I have been exceptionally helpful, I would not mind an upvote too :)

Comment: ok one more thing, what is the natural behavior of the onclick event? say I use e.preventDefault what will it do?

Comment: Depends on the element that is being clicked. You can use e.preventDefault() on a HTTP link, if you use it then the user won't be able to follow the link.